# Changing the background image of Text View whenever the button is pressed

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever the user presses the button, the text of the `TextView`, as well as the background image of `TextView`, is changed. I have created an `int[] array` to store the id of drawable to use in `TextView.setBackgroundResource(array[index])` . But on incrementing the `index` the background is not changed. I even tried hardcoded index for `array[]` but it still sets first element image.

```
 //j and drawable array are global variable.
 int j=1;
 int[] drawablearray=new int[]{R.drawable.girl,R.drawable.beach,R.drawable.flower};

 nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if(j<drawablearray.length-1){
                    j++;
                    quoteTextView.setBackgroundResource(drawablearray[j]);
                    quoteTextView.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
                }else{
                    j=0;
                    quoteTextView.setBackgroundResource(drawablearray[j]);
                    quoteTextView.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
         } 
    });
```

Comment: Try to decrease the J on else block: j--

Comment: @Ayush At first did you checked without loop condition or array decleration? Is directly assigned to textview is worked?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH It works. The first image is set as background for `TextView` but on clicking next button it is not changed. I even tried hardcoded `index` as `1` but still, it set image present at element `0`.

Comment: Because of your loop condition it will worked only one time.. At first it set only the flower drawable.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH my variable `j=1` still it is setting girl drawable.

Comment: @AyushBherwani it should be if(j<=drawablearray.length-1) ... "<=" not just "<"

Comment: @AyushBherwani You mean it set girl drawable at first time excute.

Comment: @Subzero it should be `j<drawablearray.length-1` cause if I'm having `j<=drawablearray.length-1` then it will give me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` . Suppose `j=2` and `drawablearray.length-1=2` if I'll increment value of `j+=1` it will cause exception.

Comment: @AyushBherwani so move j++ after settings background lines

Comment: @Subzero if I'll change j++ after `quoteTextView.setBackgroundResource(drawablearray[j]);` then obviously I won't get desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems everthing OK in your code.

Did you initialised `nextButton` properly?

Probably your click is not working.

**UPDATE**

I have updated your code:

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(j<drawablearray.length){
                quoteTextView.setBackgroundResource(drawablearray[j]);
                quoteTextView.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
                j++;
            }else{
                quoteTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.girl);
                quoteTextView.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
            }
        }
    });
```

For the first 3 clicks it will show three different images then sets to default image

Comment: My `nextButton` is working properly. I'm also changing the text of `quoteTextView` and it works fine.

Comment: Your code is perfectly working for me. Last try Clean -> Rebuild your project

Comment: If yes, for the worst case make sure that your drawables are unique :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181679/discussion-between-santhosh-joseph-and-ayush-bherwani).

Answer (score -1):

Your `j` variable must be 'global'. It means that it must a member of your `Activity` or `Fragment` but not a variable inside your method

Comment: My `j` variable is not inside a method. It is a `global` variable.

Comment: Global does **not** mean just a member of an activity

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the "if" condition I suggest you to use:

```
j = (j+1) % drawablearray.length;
```

Then the variable j must be a field of your java class (declare it outside every method)